# why does the return function in python is returning a value of 1 in factorial prog

Tags: python

```
#factorial prog
def fac(y):
    fact=1
    i=1
    for i in range(1,y+1):
        fact=i*fact
        return fact

x=int(input("enter no"))

y=fac(x)
print(y)
```

> why does the return function return 1

when I remove the defined function and find the factorial by same method in the main function its giving the correct answer and even in the defined function when i print fact value is providing the correct ans but only the return function is not working

can someone give me the same method code instead of recursive function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indentation level of your return statement is wrong. You should do as following:

```
#factorial prog
def fac(y):
    fact=1
    i=1
    for i in range(1,y+1):
        fact=i*fact
    return fact
```